# Python socket programming - getting a response

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I'm a newbie to socket programming in python..
I'm trying to use http head method to get a response from a webserver. In addition, calculating the elapsed time from sending a request until receiving a response.
in my code i asked for a url and a port number, if the url was correct the html contents of
that url will be shown on the browser.. and a request message will be displayed on the terminal..
for example: url=http://www.google.com , port=80,
the contents of the url "google here" will be shown on localhost:80 ...
is my code correct? and have i used the head method in the correct way? In addition to the response, i don't get a response message but a request one in the terminal.
here's my code:

```
from socket import *
import time
import requests
serverHost = input("Enter a URL: ")
serverPort = input("Enter a port number: ")
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) #Client socket that uses IPV4 and is of type TCP.
serverSocket.bind(('', int(serverPort))) #Associate server port number with this socket.
serverSocket.listen(1) #wait a client
print ("The server is ready\n")
send_time = time.time()
connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept() #listen for TCP connection requests from the client, connectionSocket is used to send and recieve data on the connection.
req_mes = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode() #Request message from the client.
print (addr) #addr is an address that's bounded to the other end of the connection (CLIENT ADDRESS).
print (req_mes) #Prints whatever data the client sends and echoes it back
connectionSocket.send(bytes('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n', 'UTF-8')) #Send the HTTP response 
header line to the connection socket
url = requests.get(serverHost)
htmltext = url.text
connectionSocket.send(htmltext.encode()) #encode the message using UTF-8
connectionSocket.close()
serverSocket.close()
recieve_time = time.time()
print('Time Elapsed:',recieve_time - send_time)
```

Comment: I'm very confused about what you're asking here. Is this code working? You shouldn't be *asking us* that, you should be *telling us* if it works or not, and describing in some detail what you expected it to do and what it is doing instead. You mention "the head method" that doesn't seem to match anything in your code.

Comment: actually I wasn't asking if it works but I asked if it was correct cause I'm still a beginner. Also "Head method is HTTP HEAD". Thank you anyway!

Comment: This is very confused code. Too many things wrong to go through them one-by-one. I recommend you find an example on the web, and follow it line by line until you understand it. Here's a well-annotated one that does almost exactly what you say you want to do (except for using `GET` instead of `HEAD`) using just the `socket` module: https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/socket-client/. There are also plenty of examples using the `requests` module. You can't just intermix the two willy-nilly (`requests` is a higher-level module built atop `socket`).

Comment: "Is this correct" is not on topic here on Stack Overflow. See [ask] for more details on how to ask appropriate questions. As for the HTTP HEAD topic, there is still no sign of it in your code. Is whatever client is connecting to your socket sending you a HEAD request? Because you're not doing any of it in the code you show. So I guess in that sense you're definitely not using HEAD requests correctly....